# Detect if collection contains data

Tags: magento

It may be a simple question, but I can't find the answer. How can I know if my Collection has no data ?

I do `$datas = Mage::getModel('zzz/zzz')->getCollection()` if I do a `$datas->getData()` it returns an empty array, but how do I know if my collection has no data without doing foreach or getData ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should avoid using `count` or your Collections. Here's why:

the `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract` (Collection Model that is inherited by almost all Magento Collections) does not have `count()` defined, so using `count` on your Collection you'll most likely end up with `Varien_Data_Collection::count()` which is very bad option, since it does a collection `load()` and then counts the loaded objects:

```
/**
 * Retireve count of collection loaded items
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function count()
{
    $this->load();
    return count($this->_items);
}
```

Having a large collection (especially EAV collection) will make result in loading ALL of your Collection data - this can take a lot of time.

Instead you should use `Varien_Data_Collection_Db::getSize()` method, which will run the SQL query to get count only, much more optimized compared to retrieving all kind of data for Collection load:

```
/**
 * Get collection size
 *
 * @return int
 */
public function getSize()
{
    if (is_null($this->_totalRecords)) {
        $sql = $this->getSelectCountSql();
        $this->_totalRecords = $this->getConnection()->fetchOne($sql, $this->_bindParams);
    }
    return intval($this->_totalRecords);
}
```

In addition to that, after `load` collection can not be modified in any way. For example you won't be able to apply additional filters of change sort order at any point after using `count()`.

So correct answer should be:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('zzz/zzz')->getCollection();
var_dump($collection->getSize());
```

Comment: i really want to bookmark this answer. or add to the list, on my profile, where i can keep the valuable answer like this one.

Comment: for doign this outside of the model itself, would `$collection->_items` work? would it be `$collection->getItems()`?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily just do an if statement like so:

```
if (!$datas->getData() || empty($datas->getData())) {
     // do things
}
```

Comment: Sorry this was the kind of things I wanted to avoid, I +1 for the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the accepted answers see benchmarks:

Tested for 750 products

`$collection->getData()`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    67,567 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 67,599 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  11,719,168 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  11,648,152 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    1,047

`$collection->getSize()`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec):    6,371 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs): 4,402 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):  140,816 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):  96,000 bytes
- Number of Function Calls:    191

`$collection->count()` or `sizeof($collection)`

- Total Incl. Wall Time (microsec): 2,130,568 microsecs
- Total Incl. CPU (microsecs):  2,080,617 microsecs
- Total Incl. MemUse (bytes):   12,899,872 bytes
- Total Incl. PeakMemUse (bytes):   13,002,256 bytes
- Number of Function Calls: 101,073

So you should go with `getSize()`.

---

<sup>Form: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179028/how-to-check-if-a-collection-has-items/179035#179035</sup>

Answer (score 2):

/**
     * Retrieve collection all items count
     *
     * @return int
     */
$collection = Mage::getModel('aaa/bbb')->getCollection()->getSize();

This is the code that's used in pagination etc and is recommended.

where 
 /**
     * Retireve count of collection loaded items
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function count()

will be useful to check for loaded items data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use;

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('zzz/zzz')->getCollection();
var_dump($collection->count());
```

Comment: It worked ! I didn't know we could count. That's great thanks.

Comment: @user1682624, you should avoid using `count()` method with your collection. I explained why in my post below

Answer (score 1):

Running a simple, standard PHP `count()` on the collection is fine here.  As long as you have properly filtered your collection, which you should always have done before getting to the point of counting it calling the `->count()` method on a collection is fine also.  As soon as you manipulate the collection in any way, it will load regardless of the method you use, so a standard PHP `count()`, calling the `->count()` method on the object, running through the collection with a `foreach()` will all load the collection in the same way as as `load()`, in fact if you trace the `load()` method back, you will see it actually runs a standard PHP `foreach()` to load collection data.

So it doesn't matter how you do it, you still can't count your collection until you know how many results have been returned from the database, so the method above is fine, but does mean extra DB calls, first to count, then to load.  A better method is just to ensure that you make your `SELECT` statements as specific as possible by narrowing them with `WHERE` clauses and so on.  If you pull the select object from a collection you have access to all of the Zend_Db_Select methods shown [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.select.html), i.e.

`$collection->getSelect()->where('......... = ?', $var);`

Comment: Actually it would had returned only 1 data or empty, so I was searching for the fastest way to do this.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, thanks for this answer. As you correctly identified, collection will be loaded eventually. The only thing is: most of the time we're using `getSize` to identify, DO WE ACTUALLY NEED TO LOAD IT OR NOT. The most typical usage of `getSize` - is to check: does our collection actually contain objects, and then either proceed (if it does) or stop your logic from execution (so collection will not be loaded). Aside from that, Collection can be used by few different Modules to prepare it, so using `count` in one will break logic of the other (look at catalog toolbar)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the product collection is $pro_collection

Now apply the following code..

```
<?php 
if(isset($pro_collection) && count($pro_collection) > 0) {
    /* Your code here */
}
?>
```