# Magento: Checking if _data is defined?

Tags: magento

This is my code:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('orderhandling/paymentmapper')->getCollection();
$payments = $collection->addFieldToFilter('id', $id);
```

Sometimes, if the **id** is not defined, the **_data** array in `$payments` is not defined. How can I check if it is not defined? I tried isset, but thats always false, no matter if the array is defined or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you just check to see if $id is not defined prior to even calling $payments?

Comment: Nope, I cant, only afterwards

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342770/detect-if-collection-contains-data

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `empty($payments)`. because id collection is empty then it return empty object. Also you can check with getData like

```
if (!$payments->getData() || empty($payments->getData())) {
     // do things
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If $id is not defined, your collection will be empty simply because magento will cast the second parameter of `addFieldToFilter` as a string.

For example:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', $id);
echo (string) $collection->getSelect();
```

Will Output:

```
SELECT 1 AS `status`, `e`.`entity_id`, `e`.`type_id`, `e`.`attribute_set_id` FROM `catalog_product_flat_1` AS `e` WHERE (e.entity_id = '')
```

which of course wont match anything.

You can verify the size of your collection by calling `$collection->getSize()`.